# pandas.dataframe.from_records not working on numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Let's create a numpy array and a list

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

m = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
l = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

This works:

```
> pd.DataFrame.from_records(m, index=l)

   0  1  2
a  1  2  3
b  4  5  6
c  7  8  9
```

This works:

```
> pd.DataFrame.from_records(m, columns=l)
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

but this does not:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(m, index=l, columns=l)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
```

This slight bug does not occur if we don't call `from_records` method. But I need it to avoid the Dataframe from copying the data.

Comment: I think this is the behavior the function should have https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.24.2/pandas/core/frame.py#L1430-L1556

Comment: Is the expected behaviour not for it to behave similarly than `pd.DataFrame` ?

Comment: You can workaround using `pd.DataFrame.from_records(m, columns=l).rename(lambda x: l[x])`. Strange though

Comment: Thanks! I ended up keeping the numpy array and handling indexing with a side `pd.Series`. It's the best solution I found performance wise